# Robot Framework - Input Text with linebreaks

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, robotframework

I'm right now testing some text editor functionality and I need to input text into my text field with line breaks and I have no idea how to simulate this behaviour.

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
Input Text  ${locator}  "text with linebreak \n"
```

Or how to split input text into multiple lines?
If I want to instead of this:

```
Input Text  ${locator}  Such a long text to input that cannot even fit on my computer's monitor size
```

Do this, split this input text into more lines:

```
Input Text  ${locator}  Such a long text to input that cannot + 
                        + even fit on my computer's monitor size
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: It seem to be not a `selenium`/`selenium-webdriver` related issue as in pure `python+selenium` this works exactly just like `.send_keys("first line \n second line")`...

Comment: try `Press Key` press an enter, and you can continue typing?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Press Key` keyword from `Selenium2Library` as the following where you want a new line, then you can continue typing.

`Press Key`  ${Textarea}  \13 `

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me

```
*** Test Cases ***
SomeRandom
    Open Browser            http://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-line-breaks.php
    Input text              id=oldText    Vivi is trying to enter \n can he do that? \n I think so \n lets try
```

Comment: And how can you locating input field to put text inside?

Comment: Here I'm just giving an example.

Comment: here id=oldText is the ${locator} were you want to enter the text.You can get the locator by inspecting the web page.I would suggest Firepath or Firebug (for mozilla).